# Prime number detector is not working

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that will determine if an inputted number is prime or not. It always returns that it is not prime. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();

        boolean y = false;
        for(int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
            if(x % i == 0) {
                y = true;
            }
            y = false;
        }

        if (y = true) {
            System.out.print(x + " is not a prime number");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(x + " is a prime number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (y = true)` should be `if (y)`. At the moment you are assigning true to `y` in your if statement. You also need to break as soon as you find a factor.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are not breaking your loop when you find a factor. Given every number is divisible by itself your condition always passes on the last iteration. Also note that you don't need to check any numbers above the square root of `x`.

Better would be:

```
boolean prime = true;
for (int n = 2; n * n <= x && prime; n++)
    prime = x % n != 0;

if (prime)
    ...
```

Or if you prefer using streams:

```
if (IntStream.range(2, n).noneMatch(x % n == 0))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor mistake:

If you say `if(y=true)`, y will be assigned the value true which is equivalent to `if(true)`. So the first check becomes true.

```
if(y == true) {
    System.out.print(x + " is not a prime number");
}
```